# Data is not updated on the UI after the API call

Tags: node.js, express

I used the below route to get data updated from the user. The form is rendering and when I click submit it redirects to the dashboard which has a table with all the data. But it's not updated.

**Update API**

```
route.post('/update-accomodation/:id',  (req, res)=>{
    if(!req.body){
        return res.status(400).send({message: "There is no data to update"})
    }
    const id=req.params.id;
    // const updatedAccomdation= 
    Accomodation.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, {useFindAndModify: false})
        .then(accomodation => {
            if (!accomodation) {
              res.status(404).send({ message: 'Cannot update the user', id });
    
            } else {
                req.session.message={
                    type: 'Success',
                    message: 'User updates Successfully',
                };
                // res.send(accomodation)
              res.redirect('/dashboard/accomodation'); 
              console.log('Test accom:',accomodation);
            }
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error in updating service information' });
          });
      });
```

What am I missing in here? Why I couldn't pass the Data?

Comment: When you make the request, do you get the success message?

Comment: Yes I do get the success message